# Bootstrap v4 grid sizes / Sass List

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap v4 variables in my project, but it is stored inside an array (`_variables.scss`):

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 544px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

How can I refer to it in my sass:

```
@media(max-width: $grid-breakpoints[xs]) {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Please, consult the SASS documentation. It is a basic feature of the language. Search for `import`.

Comment: @Kroltan your rtfm comments are unproductive, this is a q&a site and it's a legit quesiton.

Comment: @Lee At the time of writing, I probably did not have time to post a full answer. In my point of view, suggesting what to search for is at least more productive than not saying anything at all.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `$map-get`..

```
@media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, xs)) and (max-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, sm)){
  [class*='col-'] {
    font-size: 20px;
   }
}
```

**[$grid-breakpoints demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/5cGJ5lzYtR)**

There are also several breakpoint mixins in Bootstrap 4 that can be used to target a specific breakpoint...

```
@include media-breakpoint-between(sm, md){
  ...
}

@include media-breakpoint-only(lg){
  ...
}
```

**[media-breakpoint mixin demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/pYZurspxSK)**