# Using media breakpoints in Bootstrap 4-alpha

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In Bootstrap 3 I use this:

```
.something {
    padding: 5px;
    @media screen and (min-width: $screen-sm-min) { 
        padding: 20px;
    }
    @media screen and (min-width: $screen-md-min) { 
        padding: 40px;
    }
}
```

How can I do the same thing in Boostrap 4-alpha? I can't find an example in their docs. 
This is in  variables.scss

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
@include _assert-starts-at-zero($grid-breakpoints);
```

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**Update**: Bootstrap 5.

[**v5** breakpoints reference (latest)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/breakpoints/)

---

**Original answer - Bootstrap v4:** Use breakpoint mixins like this:

```
.something {
    padding: 5px;
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { 
        padding: 20px;
    }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) { 
        padding: 40px;
    }
}
```

[**v4** breakpoints reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

[**v4 alpha6** breakpoints reference](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

---

**Below full options and values.**

Breakpoint & up (toggle on value and above):

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xs) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { ... }
```

breakpoint & up values:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
// No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

breakpoint & down (toggle on value and down):

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(xs) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-down(md) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-down(lg) { ... }
```

breakpoint & down values:

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, less than 768px)
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 991px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, less than 1200px)
@media (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops)
// No media query since the extra-large breakpoint has no upper bound on its width
```

breakpoint only:

```
@include media-breakpoint-only(xs) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-only(sm) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-only(md) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-only(lg) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-only(xl) { ... }
```

breakpoint only values (toggle in between values only):

```
// Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
@media (max-width: 575px) { ... }

// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Comment: Your first code example doesn't work for me. The mixin just renders the content inside it's parent class.

Answer (score 15):

I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546031/bootstrap-v4-grid-sizes-sass-list)

As @Syden said, the mixins will work. Another option is using SASS `map-get` like this..

```
@media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, sm)){
  .something {
    padding: 10px;
   }
}

@media (min-width: map-get($grid-breakpoints, md)){
  .something {
    padding: 20px;
   }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/0TU586QNlV

---

[Bootstrap 4 Breakpoints demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/xJLrbVWAUf/breakpoints-demo)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the above, if you want to use the bootstrap media breakpoints in module level stylesheets (for example in create-react-app components), by default they will be undefined and you'll need to import the mixins and its dependencies separately into each module.

You can either import them at the top of each file:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_variables';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints';
```

Or you can create a _mixins.scss file in your scss folder, containing the lines above, and just import that file into the modules.

*Note when you include "_" in front of the file name, it won't be generated into CSS, it will be handled as a partial file that is meant to be imported only and ignored by the compiler.*

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a way of using media queries to define the different task for different sites.
It uses four breakpoints.

we have extra small screen sizes which are less than 576 pixels that small in which I mean it's size from 576 to 768 pixels.

medium screen sizes take up screen size from 768 pixels up to 992 pixels 
large screen size from 992 pixels up to 1200 pixels.

E.g Small Text

This means that at the small screen between 576px and 768px, center the text
For medium screen, change "sm" to "md" and same goes to large "lg"