# How to use Bootstrap 4 media breakpoints in SASS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

On the official [bootstrap website](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/) it says:

> Since we write our source CSS in Sass, all our media queries are
>   available via Sass mixins:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xs) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { ... }
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { ... }

// Example usage:
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .some-class {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Now, I am using SASS for my CSS, and I am also using Bootstrap, but I am combining the two only by including them in the HTML.

When i try to do something like this in my SASS file:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { ... }
```

I get an error:

> Undefined Mixin

I guess that this is because my SASS file does not know about Bootstrap, since I only include the Bootstrap in the HTML.

How can I include Bootstrap 4 into my SASS file, as a partial? (I guess that this is what I have to do...)

PS: I am using Bootstrap 4, and I would prefer a solution that does not require Bower or RubyGems etc. but just to download the Bootstrap file and include it into my SASS the old-fashioned way - if that is possible at all?

Comment: You have to `@import 'file_with_mixin_definitions.scss';` and then you can use `@include`.

Comment: Thanks, i understand that. but where can I find these mixin definitions for bootstrap 4?

Comment: Late to the party but just ran inot this issue, solved it by importing: 
 '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
 '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
 '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints';

Comment: A more complete answer following @bilcker's suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68114046/3009639

Answer (score 6):

Download the entire source code, and look in scss/mixins. The file _breakpoints.scss is the one you should have. I do the same thing, I download the source code and include the things I need in my own compiled css.

```
@import "_variables";
@import "_mixins";
@import "_grid";
```

Comment: Or @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss"; :)

Comment: Also, if you're selective in which imports you're using, make sure to first import the grid, THEN your own overwrites. With SCSS some things needs to be imported before, and some after - in this case the order is important.